# Jqgrid info dialog with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using the below code to create a info dialog with submit button.This is working well. Now i want to do some action while i click the submit button. This is not working while i use the onSubmit : function(){}. I used onClose means its working. Please help me to do this. sorry for my english..

```
var totalSelect = "";
$.jgrid.info_dialog("Select Deny Function(s) to Map", selOptin + "</ul>", $.jgrid.edit.bSubmit, {
    zIndex: 1500,
    width: gwdth,
    align: 'left',
    height: 'auto',
    onSubmit: function () {
    alert('enter hgere');
$('input[name="FunctionCheckbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    totalSelect = totalSelect + this.value + ",";
    });
    element.value = totalSelect.slice(0, -1);
    return true;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i found following way to create buttons and properly deal with their click event

```
var dialog=$.jgrid.info_dialog("Caption","text","", { 
    zIndex: 1500,
    buttons:[{
        text:"Submit", 
        id:"but_submit",  onClick:function(b) { 
            alert("submit button clicked");
        }
    }, {
        text:"Cancel", 
        id:"but_cancel", 
        onClick:function(b) {
            alert("cancel button clicked");
        }
    }]
});
```